# How do I kill a stuck ssh connection without closing the konsole window?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, signal, konsole

I use KDE (with ubuntu) and love using konsole as my terminal. I ssh a lot and every now and then (from various reasons) my connection dies and the sesson is stuck. I need to send a SIGHUP to the terminal so that the ssh session will end and I can use that window again. How do I do that with a keyboard shortcut (I hate being forced to use the mouse for Edit->Send Signal->Hangup).

Comment: If you have only one ssh connection it's enough to do a `pkill ssh`. If you have more than one you can search for the IP in the `top -c` ... You may think to pipe the `pgrep ssh` to build the `top -c` of only that processes...

Comment: A useful trick in this situation is to type `~.` to tell ssh to drop the connection (ssh only looks for it at the beginning of a line so you might have to hit return first).

Comment: @lemonsqueeze - will your suggestion work on a stuck connection? I will try it next time and report?

Comment: Yes, I use it all the time =)

Comment: @lemonsqueeze: it worked. Thanks! if you'll write it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @lemonsqueeze remark - I found a solution.

hit `~.` and a stuck ssh will end.

Not KDE related but that's good enough for my purpose.

Comment: So I am clear... `~.` sends a `SIGHUP`? Or does this answer provide an answer to a different question?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer, why is it accepted?